# Would dualbooting Windows mess up GRUB?

Tags: grub2, windows, dual-boot, 12.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 as my main OS, but have been thinking of doing some dualbooting, would making a partition specifically for Windows and installing it to that partition mess with GRUB? or Would it be fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1st option : get a CD including Boot-Repair

The easiest way to use Boot-Repair is to burn one of the following CDs and boot on it.

- Boot-Repair-Disk is a CD starting Boot-Repair automatically. (English only).
- Boot-Repair is also included in Ubuntu Secured Remix CDs (multi-languages).

Get [boot-repair](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) disk

Remarks:

- You can also install the ISO on a live-USB.
- Please note that this ISO is not an official Ubuntu image.

## 2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu

Either add `ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair` to your Software Sources via the Software Centre or, for speeds-sake, add it using a new Terminal session:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

[image: Image of Boot-Repair application]

You can run this from terminal `sudo boot-repair`

Comment: so with GRUB getting messed up will I have to redo Ubuntu too?

Comment: NO, just repair the GRUB

Comment: So it wont touch Ubuntu itsself? just the GRUB loader then?

Comment: reading required https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: I read that, I just need to know if because it touches the GRUB that it ONLY touches the GRUB not the 12.04

Comment: if you install windows in a separate partition it will not interfere with ubuntu however it will use its native MBR to boot. You WILL have to FIX the GRUB however

Comment: just want to add that although it probably won't hurt your ubuntu install, I would recommend to make a backup, just in case something goes wrong... maybe obvious, but it hurts if you forget...

Comment: Just tried it out, now I understand what exactly is going on and see how it affects it. Thanks for your patience/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will mess it up, **but**...

If you install Windows 7 / Windows XP, installer will override MBR to point to windows boot menu -- which by the way *don't allow you to boot linux*.

If you boot some live distro from flashdisk/CD/DVD after succesfull windows install and update GRUB (and edit `grub.cfg` to point to windows partition) you will be good again.

Note that Windows 8 beta behaves little differently.

Answer (score -1):

Windows would mess up GRUB, after you install Windows just use a live CD and follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.