# problems downloading boot-repair

Tags: grub2, updates

I upgraded my laptop and when I reboot it, I have problems with grub. I put the live CD and tried to download the boot-repair, by putting in the terminal
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
it downloads everything but then, when i use dash to open it, it doesn't appear in applications, where is it?

Answer (score 1):

Consult this for your answer

https://askubuntu.com/a/110374/46312

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem while trying to install programs from Live. If you can't find it, rev up terminal and enter this:

```
sudo boot-repair
```

That should start it up.

Answer (score 0):

Once installed in your Ubuntu , Boot-Repair can be run:

- either by typing "**boot-repair**" in a terminal
- or by searching "boot-repair" in the dash. (remark: if your locale is not English, it may be translated, eg "Réparateur de démarrage" in French, or "Reparador de inicialização" in Portuguese..)

If you don't have internet access on the PC you want to repair, you can use a CD with Boot-Repair pre-installed:

- [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) (English only, 32&64bits compatible, based on Debian-live so Wifi drivers are not recent).
- or [Ubuntu-Secure-Remix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix) (multi-languages, ok for Wifi, based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, run Boot-Repair from the Dash)